# MySQL view with transposed values from other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 Tables in a Google cloud sql database in MySQL, one with some references:

```
+-------+---------+--------+
| ref   | couleur | pack   |
+-------+---------+--------+
| HELLO | NOIR    | 3S2M2L |
| HELLO | WHITE   | 3S2M2L |
| WORLD | RED     | 3SM2ML |
| WORLD | GREEN   | 3SM2ML |
+-------+---------+--------+
```

One with some packs:

```
+--------+------+------+------+------+------+
| pack   | S    | M    | L    | SM   | ML   |
+--------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 3S2M2L |    3 |    2 |    2 |    0 |    0 |
| 3SM2ML |    0 |    0 |    0 |    3 |    2 |
+--------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

I need to have a list of existing references with sizes:

```
+-------+---------+--------+
| ref   | couleur | taille |
+-------+---------+--------+
| HELLO | NOIR    | S      |
| HELLO | NOIR    | M      |
| HELLO | NOIR    | L      |
| HELLO | WHITE   | S      |
| HELLO | WHITE   | M      |
| HELLO | WHITE   | L      |
| WORLD | RED     | SM     |
| WORLD | RED     | ML     |
| WORLD | GREEN   | SM     |
| WORLD | GREEN   | ML     |
+-------+---------+--------+
```

I am trying with a case when like this but it seems like when I add another 'case when' replacing the 'null', it gives me an error.

```
select 
    r.ref, 
    r.couleur,
    (case when p.S > 0 then '  S' else null end
    ) as 'taille'
from _refs r
left join _packs p on r.pack = p.pack
;
```

I am kind of starting SQL, thanks a lot for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sizes of the clothing (?) are hard coded in your database model. The solution is to union five separate queries, as in:

```
select * from (
  select r.ref, r.couleur, 'S' as taille 
    from _refs r join _packs p on p.pack = r.pack and p.s > 0
  union
  select r.ref, r.couleur, 'M'
    from _refs r join _packs p on p.pack = r.pack and p.m > 0
  union
  select r.ref, r.couleur, 'L'
    from _refs r join _packs p on p.pack = r.pack and p.l > 0
  union
  select r.ref, r.couleur, 'SM'
    from _refs r join _packs p on p.pack = r.pack and p.sm > 0
  union
  select r.ref, r.couleur, 'ML'
    from _refs r join _packs p on p.pack = r.pack and p.ml > 0
) x
order by ref, couleur, taille
```